# Error in Assignment

Tags: matrix, assignment

I want to create a matrix with each element updated as per the formula, whose inputs are dependent on the location of element in the matrix.

```
Zphat[t] = ConstantArray[0, {4, 2, 2}]
```

The assignment is done using this:

```
For[i = 1, i < 5, i++, For [j = 1, j < 3, j++ , For [n = 1, n < 3, n++, For[k = 1, k < 5, k++, Zphat[t][[1, j, n]] = Zphat[t][[i, j, n] + D[zdot[t][i,j], {q[t][[1, k]], 1}]*smat[t][[k, n]]]]]]
```

I have checked the matrix dimensions used. zdot and smat are the appropriate matrices derived earlier.

Error message: 
**Set::setps: Zphat[t] in the part assignment is not a symbol.**

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but as you will often hear here, using `For` is going to make your life much, much worse. In fact using procedural code in Mathematica will just generally be slow and more work than using the built in functional constructs. There's a very good Q/A here on good alternatives to `For`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Zphat[t] = ConstantArray[0, {4, 2, 2}]` means "whenever you see the expression `Zphat[t]`, replace it with the result of evaluating the `ConstantArray` expression."

There's a special case of `Part` that allows you to modify part of an expression that's bound to a symbol. But `Zphat[t]` isn't a symbol: it's a more complicated expression, so that special case doesn't apply.

Generally, the easy way to construct a matrix according to a formula is to use `Table` rather than constructing it and modifying it.

To answer the question in the comments:

```
x = {1, 2};
```

binds the expression `{1,2}` to `x`. This means "when you evaluate `x`, rewrite it as `{1,2}`". However, `=` (`Set`) holds its left hand side unevaluated, and does a special thing when it's a `[[]]` (`Part`) expression:

```
x[[2]] = 3;
x
(* {1, 3} *)
```

Note that it can modify any expression this way, not just a `List`:

```
x = y + z;
x[[2]] = 3;
x
(* 3 + y *)
```

Comment: Could you explain what `an expression that's bound to a symbol` mean?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use `Table` to solve the expression. I have performed the calculation in 2 steps.

```
Zphat[t] =  Table[D[zdot[t][[i, j]], {q[t][[1, k]], 1}]*smat[t][[k, n ]], {i, 4} , {j, 2}, {n, 2}, {k, 4}]
```

and for summation over the variable k

```
Zphatfinal[t] = Table[Sum[Zphat[t][i, j, n, k], {k, 2}], {i, 4} , {j, 2}, {n, 2}]
```

Also, refer to this before using `For` - [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica)